# Get nearby places through Lucene.net 3.0.3 or newest

Tags: c#, indexing, geospatial, spatial, lucene.net

I'm looking for samples on how to index and query using spatial queries. I need to query places near by, sorting by distance (asc) using Lucene.net 3.0.3 or earlier.

All I got was some samples using older versions of Lucene.Net (older than 3.0.3) but I heard that Lucene.net have had a breaking changes on spatial index since version 3.0.3.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use 3.0.3 or earlier and you found samples for earlier than 3.0.3 - what's your question? (Note that _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..")_

Comment: I would not recommend starting out wit lucene.net 3.0.3 , try 4.8 Instead por favor!